# Check if a point belongs to area enclosed by Bezeir curve using GDI

Tags: algorithm, gdi, hit

I want to check if a specified coordinate is inside an area enclosed by a [Bezier curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve). Is there specific function in GDI I can use? If no, how could I do this manually? 
My Bezier curve sets by its points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How much queries are you going to do?
If performance is not very important, you may create GDI region and check whether point is inside:

```
BeginPath
draw enclosed path with PolyBezier and other functions
EndPath
PathToRegion
PtInRegion
```

If there are many query points, it would better to make analytic solution - calculate the number of intersections of (horizontal) ray from point with Bezier curve (cubic equation solution is needed). If this number is odd  - point is inside (there are some subtleties with double roots on curve cusps etc)